# re-shaping a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a data frame like below:

[image]

How can I change the data frame to make below table using pandas?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe as text? Also, it's unclear if any of the data is intended to be the index of your dataframe.

Comment: @BigP your expected output seems like a pivot on countries, you would require pd.melt + pivot , check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.melt` works well here:

```
df.melt(id_vars='Year', value_vars=['Australia', 'England', 'China'], value_name='Values')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for having the countries grouped as index :

using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars='Year').pivot(index='variable',columns='Year').stack()

                   value
variable    Year    
Australia   2000    x
            2001    a
            2002    l
China       2000    z
            2001    c
            2002    n
England     2000    y
            2001    b
            2002    m
```